# Is it practically okay to use darlington triple?

Tags: high-current, darlington, practical

I need to control a very high current in my project. I'm planning to use darlington formation with three transistors.

I'm planning to use [BQ24450](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24450.pdf) to charge a group of 12V acid-lead battery.

[image]

BQ24450 supplies only 25mA current to control the switching BJT transistor. Charge current will be variable up to 80A. I haven't decided for transistor model yet, but it looks like a darlington pair will not create enough current gain since power BJTs usually have low current gain. Therefore, I decided to make a darlington group with three BJTs.

[image]

Is making darlington formation with three transistors practically okay? I have never seen it before in a professional design. Could it cause any problems (like leakage currents always keeping the BJTs on causing them to burn eventually)? If yes, are there any measures I can take?

Comment: Can you find a BJT that will deal with 80A of collector current and 8A of base current?

Comment: Keep in mind the voltage drop of the combined equivalent transistor.  A darlington arrangement is not for for high current due to the voltage drop and therefore the large heat dissipation.

Comment: The real solution here is a DC-DC converter with a constant-current output. Trying to run 80A through a linear regulator is a generally bad idea, unless there are very, very specific reasons a switch-mode converter wouldn't work.

Answer (score 5):

A darlington triple will drop about 2.1V across it at normal currents of up to 10A - I can see it being a bit higher at 80A, maybe around 3V - this means it will dissipate a power of 240W and this doesn't consider that the regulator is a linear type and there maybe as much as 5V constantly across the transistor (darlington or FET or single BJT).

This means a whopping great heatsink and a potential power dissipation of up to (and possibly exceeding) 400W.

May I recommend that you consider a switching battery charger using a big P channel mosfet - it might dissipate 50W in comparison.